# How to add link to original image in WordPress NextGen Lightbox

Tags: wordpress, lightbox, prettyphoto, nextgen-gallery

I use NextGen Gallery plugin in WordPress with Lightbox javascript effect. So I have active divs for next and previous image:

```
<div class="pp_hoverContainer">
<a class="pp_next" href="#">next</a>
<a class="pp_previous" href="#">previous</a>
</div>
```

This divs covers my image div and that's why I can't save current image by clicking right button mouse as it was without pp_hoverContainer.

I need 'save image' or 'open original image' functionality.

Here is jquery.prettyPhoto.js code which is in use. Please, help me insert here a button "Save this image" or "Open image in new window"

```
    /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Class: prettyPhoto
        Use: Lightbox clone for jQuery
        Author: Stephane Caron (http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com)
        Version: 3.1.5
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
...
```

Download lquery.pretty.js - http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/demos/prettyPhoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/prettyPhoto_uncompressed_3.1.5.zip

You can look my gallery - [http://2013.infoforum.ru/#!lightbox[ngg-images-2]/0/](http://2013.infoforum.ru/#!lightbox%5Bngg-images-2%5D/0/)

here i cant save image by clicking right button of mouse:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin [Wp Jquery Lightbox](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-jquery-lightbox/). It has buildin download option, which will give you original image url.

Comment: but NextGen plugin is more beautiful. That's why I spent so time to make it do what I want.

Comment: Yeah i'm saying that Use combination NextGen+Wp Jquery Lightbox :)

Comment: Prateek, did you implement them somewhere. Give a link to look, please.

Comment: look picture in question (added screen from your site). There I cant save image by clicking mouse.

Comment: oops sorry.. !! the plugin was rested :/ check now :) i've added a download button, which will open the image.